# Jquery: set <option> checked based on <select> attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I'm trying to write a simple jquery script that would loop through *all* `<select>` elements on the page and pick up an attribute named selected and set option value to selected based on that.

example:

```
<select selected="2">
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

On the example above the code would set option "two" to selected.

What is the cleanest way to write this?

**edit:**

For clarification, the main problem with my question and the example above is that I was using reserved keyword 'selected'. I would suggest using another attribute name (I changed my to data-selected, this is even valid with html5-spec :-) ).

```
<select data-selected="2">
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What did you try yet so far?

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get my version (using .each iteration) to work therefore I asked the question here.

Comment: So, you should post that here..

Comment: Why? There is no reason for me to post incorrect code samples.

Comment: The cleanest way to do it is by not iterating through all the elements in the DOM but by targeting a specific `select` element. At the very worst grab only the `select` elements and cycle through those.

Comment: I'm looking for general solution that I can include to all form pages. I want to get rid of server side selection code.

Comment: @mikkom Because we can identify the problem with your code and provide you answer.

Comment: The question is quite clearly stated so I don't think there is need for incorrect samples. I'm sure someone proficient in jquery can write the code in minute.

Comment: why you want to loop to get selected value ?

Comment: I want to use this script to set option value based on '<select>' attribute therefore getting rid of server side code that involves setting selected there.

Comment: Only one select on the page will have that attribute at a time ?

Comment: No, I want to use this as a general solution. Any <select> attribute can have this value and will have the option set to selected, there might very well be 10 <select> fields and every one of them could use this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selected` is a reserved property.  No matter what you set it to, jQuery will return its value as "selected."

Instead, you can access the DOM [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) collection directly, like this:

```js
$('select[selected]').val(function() {
  return this.attributes.selected.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select selected="1">
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select selected="2">
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select selected="3">
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer. I got my code working too after I renamed the attribute to selected_value and the code above works for keyword attribute that I mistakenly used.

Answer (score 1):

`options` have `selected` attributes. You can't have a `selected` attribute on a `select` element like that. You can have a data-attribute, or a name instead perhaps.

```
$('select[data-selected="1"]')
```

or

```
$('select[name="1"]')
```

To get the option with a value of 1 you can simply do and add a selected attribute to it:

```
$('select[data-selected="1"] option[value="1"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/m2cLh4uy/)

Comment: Thank you, naming the extra attribute based on html5 spec is a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, `selected` is a reserved keyword.

Tweaked your html and this is now working:

```
<select mysv="2">
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

$("select").each(function(){
    var sv = $(this).attr("mysv");
  $(this).find("option[value="+sv+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I finally ended with. It has one extra thing that other solutions didn't have, checking of attribute availability. Other solutions will set the select field blank (even if there are no blank options available) if the attribute is missing.

```
$("select").each(function() {
   var selected_val = $(this).attr("data-selected");
   if(selected_val)
      $(this).val(selected_val);
});
```